# Usage of PRESENTLY

Tags: usage

The dictionary lists one of the meanings of **presently** as *nowadays*, however for some reason it doesn't quite sound right in this sentence translated from a Russian source that literally start with the Russian word for *nowadays*:

> **Presently**, your appearance can affect your career growth and your
>   interpersonal relationships.

Does it seem strange to anyone else? If so, what property of **presently** makes it not quite idiomatic here?

Comment: What dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrases **at present** and **presently**

> The property taxes are  being placed {presently | at present} in escrow.

do not mean **nowadays**.  They mean, "for now", or "currently" of "for the time being".

When we want to mean "nowadays", we wouldn't say:

> {Presently |at present } <sup>unidiomatic</sup> some people use their phone far more often to text than they
>   use it to place voice calls.

We would say "These days" or "nowadays" instead of "presently" or "at present" there.